# When shall I use multiple comparison adjustment if I perform a series of Chi-square?

Tags: chi-squared-test, multiple-comparisons, bonferroni

I am presenting some descriptive statistics about % of access to a service in different regions (12) of a country in my bar graph over two time period points. As the results are based on 12 2X2 tables I also performed a Chi square to put an asterisks in the graph whether the difference in % is significant over time. I chose the Chi-square over the McNemar's test because results for the two different time points are not paired up (are driven from using two survey data-sets where only a sub-portion of the respondents were the same). 
As I am analysing 12 different sub-samples (each region) of my dataset I was wondering if I still have to use the Bonferroni correction (p=0.05/12) for multiple comparisons or that correction only stands if I was considering different outcomes from the same sub-sample.
Thanks in advance,
Vincent

Comment: Are you comparing the 12 groups all toghether right?

Comment: Yes I am. I mean, I am presenting them all together, but at same time, each 2X2 table is using only a sub-sample of my dataset, and each sub-sample doesn't overlap with the others....

Comment: I think you should performa  post-hoc analysis with bonferroni correction for multiple comparisons since you want to compare different groups together. Though even if i'm quite confident about this i'm not 100% sure so i won't post is as an answer.